# $\exists x Px \land \exists x Qx$ does not imply $\exists x (P x \land Q x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am pretty confused by this. 
We know that $\phi : = \exists x Px \land \exists x Qx $ 
    does not imply  $\psi : = \exists x (P x \land Q x)$,
    as for the model $M$ with domain $\{0,1\}$ with $P := \{0\}$ and $Q := \{1\}$,
    we have that $M \models \phi$, $M \not \models \psi$. But, seemingly:

\begin{eqnarray}
 \exists x Px \land \exists x Qx \implies & \lnot ( \lnot ( \exists x Px \land \exists x Qx))\\
             \implies   & \lnot ( \lnot \exists x Px \lor \lnot \exists x Qx)\\
             \implies  &  \lnot (\forall x \lnot Px \lor \forall x \lnot Qx))\\
             \implies  &  \lnot (\forall x (\lnot Px \lor \lnot Qx ))\\
             \implies  &  \exists x \lnot ( \lnot P x \lor \lnot Q x) \\
             \implies  &  \exists x (P x \land Q x) ,            
 \end{eqnarray}

where $(3) \implies (4)$ by the schema 
    $\forall x A x \lor \forall x B x \implies \forall x (A x \lor B x)$;
    (2) $\implies (3), (4) \implies (5)$ by quantifier/negation relations; and 
    $(1) \implies (2), (5) \implies (6)$ by De Morgan's laws. 
    What went wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lnot (\forall x \lnot Px \lor \forall x \lnot Qx)) \Rightarrow \lnot (\forall x (\lnot Px \lor \lnot Qx ))\\$$

is not correct.

It is equivalent to

$$
\varphi ~ =: ~\forall x \lnot Px \lor \forall x \lnot Qx \Leftarrow \forall x (\lnot Px \lor \lnot Qx ) ~ := \psi\\$$

Consider your examplary $\{P,Q\}$-structure $A$ over the universe $\{0,1\}$ with $P=\{0\}$ and $Q=\{1\}$.

Now $A \models \psi$ but $A \not \models \varphi$.

This the schema 
    $\forall x A x \lor \forall x B x \Rightarrow \forall x (A x \lor B x)$ is correct but you have been using it the otherway around which is generally not a correct implication.

Comment: Great thank you! This answer also explains why moving from the last statement to the first is indeed valid. I made the error that I can substitute implications of logical expressions for those expressions e.g. P $\land$ Q implies P does not entail $\lnot(P \land Q)$ implies $\lnot(P)$

Comment: Results such as these are easy (and fun!) to check using the method of analytic tableaux. [I drew one up for you in an answer but my phone's not letting me share it for some reason.] I recommend learning how to use them :)